# texture turns purple when image sequence offset changes

Tags: texturing, shaders, faces

i have this problem with the image sequence where the only frame that appears is the first on while the others appear purple, i made it so the textures appear overlapping but for some reason when i change the offset its purple. i even tried adding the textures over and over again but it didnt work. help[image: preview]

Comment: Pink appears for two reasons: either the texture is not available to blender (it has been moved to a different folder on the hard drive or deleted), or the texture mapping is incorrect. Notice that there is a warning on your computer on the bottom right. Explore the error message.

Comment: @susu i did add the textures over and over again and didnt move it, it still didnt work, oh and that was a onedrive notification

Comment: You can always [edit] your post to write additional information about your project. No one was looking over your shoulder when you created it or knows what kind of "tutorial" you followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the textures i used had to be numerically named for blender to get it right